# Remoting to azure webrole

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to remote to my Azure webrole and I am getting a message saying [image]  .I was able to remote into this webrole while I was in office network.But when I am at home its giving me this error message .It looks like ,the remote computer is not available on the network.

**Question**

How can I resolve this issue so that I can connect to my webrole?

Comment: Do you have something blocking RDP on your home network?  Perhaps blocking RDP to networks outside your own?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you might need to add a certificate to your local environment?
http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/Azure/SetupEnvironment.aspx

Comment: No certificate is required to RDP to an Azure VM.

Comment: Hmmm, if you go to the cloud service => Configure => Connect button down the bottom, there will be a drop down list to choose a certificate from... Don't know how to insert image yet...

Comment: That certificate is for encrypting the password in the cscfg file, but not for actually connecting via RDP.